# How to swap the two numbers in string in specific way?

Tags: java, android, string, sorting

Hi I want to swap the numbers in string form in specific way.

For example :

If i have `10325476` then it should return `01234567` whatever i had tried so far is i just swapped the the pair of two numbers in String.

**EDIT**
if i have `01AB3423` then Answer should be `10BA4332` Following is my current implementation which gives me desired output.

```
char temp1 = c1[0];
c1[0] = c1[1];
c1[1] = temp1;

char temp2=c1[2];
c1[2]=c1[3];
c1[3]=temp2;

char temp3=c1[4];
c1[4]=c1[5];
c1[5]=temp3;

char temp4=c1[6];
c1[6]=c1[7];
c1[7]=temp4;
```

I have done this for all 8 numbers but its a static way. And i know its not a correct way to do this.I want to do this dynamically as well.is there any other way to implement this?

Any idea and advice will be appreciated.

Comment: That is not swapping, that is sorting.

Comment: in which way you want to swap your String?

Comment: @imrankhan i want to swap the each of pair in string

Comment: @juned : see @ Rohit Jain Answer this will help you more

Comment: It is still not clear.  You want to swap each pair?  Or sort no matter what order the digits are in?

Comment: @Simon. Well, you are right. Just saw the example again, and saw that swapping each pair, and sorting would give same result. juned, cna you specify clearly do you actually want to sort, or swap every pair of numbers sequentially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: -**

From your latest edit, it seems like you want to swap consecutive pairs of characters in your string. You would need a `loop` in that case.

Try this code: -

```
String str = "BA34CD567";
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
    char temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = temp;
}

System.out.println(arr);
```

**Output : -**

```
AB43DC657
```

I have incremented `i` by `2` in the loop, because you are considering `two elements` on each iteration.

---

**Old Answer : -**

Just 3 steps: -

- Convert your string to char array. (`str.toCharArray()`)
- Sort your char array. (`Arrays.sort(arr))`. Remember, `Arrays.sort` does not return the sorted array. It sorts the array in place.
- And then print your array. (Well, you know how to do this)

Comment: Thanks for response,i didn't get this line `Arrays.sort does not return the sorted array. It sorts the array in place` can explain it in detail?

Comment: @RohitJain You beat me to it! Nice answer without exactly coding it for them.

Comment: @juned.. When you do `Arrays.sort` you don't need to store it the result in an array. It will aumatically sort your array. Just print it after you used `Array.sort`.

Comment: @juned.. xagyg has given an implementation for the algorithm I posted. Now you have both. You can understand it easily now.

Comment: @juned. So, you really wanted to sort and not swap every number pair. What output do you want for - `4352678`?

Comment: HI @RohitJain i have some problem with this its doesn't give the desired output, if i have `BABABABA` then it should return `ABABABAB` but with this it returns `AAAABBBB` for `4352678` it should give `34257608`

Comment: @juned.. That is why I asked for clarificatin that you want sorting or swapping. See my last comment in this question.

Comment: @RohitJain yeah my mistake, now it seems absolutely correct. Thanks Again

Comment: @RohitJain i need you some help in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721637/method-to-pass-a-only-two-element-of-byte-array

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some sorting algorithms, such as *bubble sort* (if it is a small set of numbers), *merge sort*, *quicksort*, and others. This is what you seem to want to do -- *sorting*.