# Method to pass a only two element of byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am developing an application in which i need to pass a array of 12 element. i am sending this array as a request using socket. I have lots of button on which i am performing this action.

The whole array remains same to send different action except the element no 10 and 11 gets changed for different buttons.

for example i am sending this values for Button 1 to ON

```
byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
{   
    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, 
    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06, 
    (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x00, 
    (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x00 
};
```

Here only element no 10`(0x01)` will changed for Button 2 which will be `(0x02)` and  i am changing element no 11 for ON|OFF.

So i want to create such a method in which i can pass this two elements only. if i pass `(0x01,0xff)` button 1 ON and `(0x01,0x00)` button 1 off.

If you have any idea give me some guidance and advice to achieve my goal. currently i am passing all those elements for all buttons. but i want to do this dynamically.

**Edit**
Button 1 OFF

```
byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
    {   
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06, 
        (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 
    };
```

Button 2 on

```
byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
    {   
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06, 
        (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x02,(byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x00 
    };
```

Button 2 off

```
byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
    {   
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06, 
        (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x02,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 
    };
```

Button 3 ON

```
byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
    {   
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06, 
        (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x03,(byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x00 
    };
```

button 3 Off

```
byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
    {   
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06, 
        (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x00, 
        (byte) 0x03,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 
    };
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: "Pass" how? I'm afraid the question is really quite unclear about what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: Instead of passing 12 elements i just want to change those 2 elements for different operation.

Comment: You'll have to define a new service method that treats the input as *updates* to the existing data.

Comment: @Andreas_D can't i create a method like `fooMethod(byte,byte) in which i can pass diffrent values ?

Comment: You said that `0x01` is for button 1 and `0x02` is for button 2. But again you are saying this: - `(0x00,0x00) button 1 off`. So why is it `0x00` for button 1 here?

Comment: sorry its my mistake, i corrected that @RohitJain

Comment: Ok now, if you are only concerned about that 2 values, then why are you creating an array at all? Can you post the scenario where you need to use it?

Comment: I am sending this request to hardware which accepts byte array of 12 element,and gives me response.

Comment: @juned what is wrong with `set(byte [] data, byte v1, byte v2) {data[BUTTON_INDEX] = v1; data[ON_OFF_INDEX] = v2); }` or `setButton(byte [] data, byte button) { data[BUTTON_INDEX] = button; }`. You can encapsulate all these functionality into some `Data` class which holds the data array itself and internal logic and exports `setButton(byte button); on(); off();` methods.

Comment: @juned.. So you are saying that, your this array is fixed. And you want some way to change those two elements only, by passing 2 extra parameters. So, you want to pass three parameters to your method?

Comment: @juned.. You can toggle the `ON/OFF` state by `XORing` with `0xff`. `0xff ^ 0xff = 0x00`, and `0x00 ^ 0xff = 0xff`

Comment: yeah my array is fixed to 12 element, i just want to change those two element only. its just two parameters @RohitJain

Comment: @juned. And for specifying a button say x, you can do - `0x01 * x`. e.g: - for x = 4, `0x01 * 4 = 0x04`. Now you need to make sure that your multiplication result is not out of range of `byte`.

Comment: @khachik yeah that way might work but i have problem in implement those values to index 10 and 11.

Comment: @juned. And are you actually having different arrays for each button? Because element 10 is specific for every button right? What problem are you having implementing it to index 10 and 11?

Comment: @RohitJain element 10 is specific for each elelment like 0x01 for button 1,0x02 for button 2 etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20619/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-juned)

Comment: @RohitJain, i need your small help

Comment: @RohitJain i have fixed byte array to read response of different button status and while reading and writing too frequently on socket, i am getting application not responding dialog. this happens when i am setting poll interval time too low i.e 100ms. thanks foe respond by the way :)

Comment: @RohitJain give me some rough idea,how do i fix this ? i have asked to many colleagues but no one able fix this problem

Comment: @juned. Please post a new question with details. It's hard to guess what went wrong by reading your comment.

Comment: @RohitJain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456552/applkcation-not-responding-while-performing-a-read-write-operation-on-socket-too

Comment: @RohitJain also please check is your idea is implemented correctly or not http://paste.ubuntu.com/1558355/

Comment: @RohitJain please help me to implement your logic :)